# Nested splitting of a sequence using expl3

Tags: expl3

In the MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand \DefGrRules { m } { \inft_def_gr_rules:n { #1 } }

\NewDocumentCommand \GrammarShowRules { } { \inft_grammar_show_rules: }

\seq_new:N \l__inft_gr_rules_seq

\cs_new:Nn \inft_def_gr_rules:n
{
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__inft_gr_rules_seq { #1 }   
}

\cs_new:Nn \inft_grammar_show_rules:
{
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l_tmpa_seq \l__inft_gr_rules_seq
  {
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpb_seq {->} { ##1 }
    \seq_show:N \l_tmpb_seq
    \seq_count:N \l_tmpb_seq
    { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpb_seq { 1 } }
    & \to
    { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpb_seq { 2 } }
  }
  \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { \\ }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\DefGrRules{S -> X | , X -> aXYZ | aYZ, ZY -> YZ, aY -> ab, bY -> bb, bZ -> bc, cZ -> cc}

\begin{align*}
\GrammarShowRules
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

`\l_tmpb_seq` seems to have two items as confirmed by `\seq_show:N \l_tmpb_seq`. However, `\seq_count:N \l_tmpb_seq` returns 0, and the commands for accessing the items expand to nothing. What is the reason for this?

My intention is to replace `->` by `\to`, furthermore `|` by `\mathrel{} \middle| \mathrel{}` and to process all the other parts by a further command that is omitted in the MWE, since not even the splitting works as desired.

Comment: The third argument to `\seq_set_map:NNn` is subject to full expansion, so it cannot contain directly assignments.

Comment: @egreg O.k., my approach is obviously wrong and needs to be replaced. However, why does `\seq_show:N` display a sequence with two items if the assignment is not supposed to work?

Comment: I guess it's just a coincidence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third argument to `\seq_set_map:NNn` is subject to full expansion. You can use an expandable method for splitting the argument at `->`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand \DefGrRules { m } { \inft_def_gr_rules:n { #1 } }

\NewDocumentCommand \GrammarShowRules { } { \inft_grammar_show_rules: }

\seq_new:N \l__inft_gr_rules_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \inft_def_gr_rules:n
 {
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__inft_gr_rules_seq { #1 }   
 }

\cs_new:Nn \inft_grammar_show_rules:
 {
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l_tmpa_seq \l__inft_gr_rules_seq
   {
    \__inft_gr_split:w ##1 \q_stop
   }
  \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { \\ }
 }
\cs_new:Npn \__inft_gr_split:w #1 -> #2 \q_stop
 {
  \exp_not:n { #1 & \to #2 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\DefGrRules{
  S -> X |,
  X -> aXYZ | aYZ,
  ZY -> YZ,
  aY -> ab,
  bY -> bb,
  bZ -> bc,
  cZ -> cc
}

\begin{align*}
\GrammarShowRules
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The double backslash needs to be removed from `\__inft_gr_split:w` since it is already part of `\seq_use:Nn`.

Comment: @Matthias Yes, you're right

Answer (score 3):

Just for the sake of variety, here's a way to achieve your typesetting objective via a LuaLaTeX-based approach. The preamble below sets up two LaTeX macros, `\DefGrRules` and `\GrammarShowRules`, which act as wrappers for two corresponding Lua functions, called `DefGrRules` and `GrammarShowRules`. The former function employs Lua's powerful `string.gsub` function to do most of the work.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align*' env.

%% Lua-side code
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
```

```lua
Rule = ""  -- initialize string variable    
function DefGrRules ( s )
    s = s:gsub ( "->" , "&\\to" )
    s = s:gsub ( "|"  , "\\mathrel{}\\vert\\mathrel{}" )
    s = s:gsub ( ","  , "\\\\"  )
    Rule = s -- store result in string variable "Rule"
end    
function GrammarShowRules ()
    tex.sprint ( "\\begin{align*}" .. Rule .. "\\end{align*}" )
end
```

```tex
\end{luacode}

%% TeX-side code    
\newcommand\DefGrRules[1]{\directlua{DefGrRules(\luastringN{#1})}}
\newcommand\GrammarShowRules{\directlua{GrammarShowRules()}}

\begin{document}   
\DefGrRules{S -> X | , X -> aXYZ | aYZ, ZY -> YZ, aY -> ab, bY -> bb, bZ -> bc, cZ -> cc}    
\GrammarShowRules  
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a very nice alternative.