# Mixing expl3 and luacode

Tags: luatex, expl3, luacode

What do you think about mixing `expl3` and `luacode`? Is this an "accepted approach" or rather a "bad practise" or something in between?

Consider, for example, my previous question [Nested splitting of a sequence using expl3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/402818/) and the excellent answers by [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/) and [Mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5001/). I have started writing a package based on `expl3`. In this specific case, however, the LuaTeX solution is much more concise. This is why I would tend to call a LuaTeX function from an expl3 function.

Comment: nothing wrong with mixing lua and expl3 so long as you are writing luatex-specific package code. Personally I find it easier to use `\directlua` than the wrappers provided by the `luacode` package, but opinions differ on that.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It's unfortunately really hard to get `%` and `#` in Lua without the help of the `luacode` package.  I asked Joseph whether I should write something similar for `expl3` but [he declined](https://github.com/latex3/latex3/issues/371#issuecomment-309263617).

Comment: not _really_  hard (If we don't already provide macros holding `%` (ie `\@percentchar` and `#` you could easily define them.

Comment: @HenriMenke It's more that I'm of the same mind as David: for any non-trivial piece of Lua code, a separate file is the best place for it to go. (One can happily have it and the matching TeX in a single `.dtx`.) In any case, what we've tried to do with the Lua support in `expl3` is be quite cautious: my earlier stuff was not so great so I cut it back to what I _know_ we need.

Comment: One of the goals of expl3 is having a basis that provides (fairly) decent programming constracts that actually work more or less seemlessly across different engines (and in fact can work across different formats). If you mix in Lua code then you loose that feature, ie that your package does work with both LuaTeX and pdfTeX --- so it depends on what you want/need and which user base should be able to use it afterwards. As to what we are eventually going to provide there in terms of "official" support that is still a bit further down in the future, so we aren't yet zooming in on one interface.

Comment: I suppose an important factor in the "expl3 or Lua code" debate is your personal, prior familiarity with `expl3`- and Lua-based programming. Speaking purely for myself, I find Lua-based programming fairly easy to do -- at least for the stuff I need to get done in my own papers. This, in turn, is mainly (entirely?!) the case because I was already familiar with Lua and because the "hooks" provided by Lua(La)TeX (the `\directlua` macro and the machinery of the `luacode` package) are rather straightforward and easy to master. Naturally, other people's mileage with Lua may (and will surely) vary.